# How to view object names in user spool space

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How to view object names  in user spool space teradata without asking a DBA

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Spool space typically refers to disk space that is available to run queries.  If you want to use the objects under a specific database / user, you can run the `HELP` command in SQL Assistant: `HELP DATABASE <db_name>;` or `HELP USER <user_name>;`

Comment: Typo - **"view the objects"**, not "use the objects"

Comment: I want to clear my spool space but not clear all the tables that occupy space selectively clear tables

Comment: Intermediate spool space is automatically released (indicated by *(Last use)* in explain). Result spools a released when the last row was retunred to the client. If you talk about *Volatile Tables*, and you forgot the names you can get a list using `help volatile table;` and then simply `drop table ...`